# Leetcode shows wrong answer even though i get correct answer in another compiler (javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am starting in leetcode and in one of the questions, it shows the wrong answer in the leetcode compiler even though I get the correct answer in other compilers. Is there something wrong with my output format or any other? (i am using javascript)

question: Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order.
Example 1:

```
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9 Output: [0,1]Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

link: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

my answer:

```
let twoSum = (nums, target)=>{
    for(let i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
    var flag = 0;
        let remValue = target - nums[i];
        let index = nums.indexOf(remValue);
        if(index == i){
            continue;
        }
        if(index!= -1){
           // console.log(`[${i},${index}]`);
            console.log(i, index)
          break;
        }
    }   
}

const nums = [2,7,11,15];
const target = 9;
twoSum(nums, target)
```

Answer (score 0):

for this specific problem you need to return the answer from the function you just defined (twoSum), and there's no need to output it to console log.

"You can return the answer in any order."

```
if(index!= -1){
    return [i, index]
}
```